# Evolution of a general state - Quantum Quench

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose we have a state prepared in ground state of some Hamiltonian.  Say

$$H \vert\psi_{0}(g)\rangle = E_{0}\vert\psi_{0}(g)\rangle$$

If I evolve this state with a different Hamiltonian

$$ \exp({-iH_{2}t})\vert\psi_{0}\rangle = \sum_{n} \exp(-iE_{n}^{'}t) \langle\phi_{n}\vert\psi_{0}\rangle \vert\phi_{n}\rangle $$

where $H_{2}\vert\phi_{n}\rangle = E_{n}^{'}\vert \phi_{n} \rangle$

(Q1)  My doubt is whether the state evolved by different Hamiltonian can be written in the basis of new Hamiltonian for a very short time $t<<1$.

(Q2)  This is called quantum quenching.  Obviously at $t=0$, the state of the system is still the ground state of old Hamiltonian.  The state starts changing once the evolution is started, how long should i wait for the state to evolve, so that the state actually evolved to new eigenbasis for new hamiltonian? Maybe this is a stupid question to ask! correct me if I am wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always write any state in terms of any complete basis, including the eigenbasis of any given Hamiltonian.

For your second question none of the terms in the expansion
$$
e^{-\imath H_2 t} |\psi\rangle = \sum_n e^{-\imath E_n t} \langle \phi_n|\psi\rangle |\phi_n\rangle 
$$
ever decay, so the initial state will never decay into an eigenstate of the new Hamiltonian. You need some form of non-unitary dynamics, say by interacting with an external bath, to bring the state into an eigenstate of the new Hamiltonian

Comment: yes, the initial state will never decay into an eigenstate of the new Hamiltonian completely, but the contribution from new eigenstate is also there in the evolved state right?  I have seen numerous papers which talks about quantum quenching, where the system is quenched across (Phase Transition) PT and extracted PT critical exponents. Without the contribution from new eigenstate, how is it possible to extract such properties of PT.

Comment: What do you mean the "contribution" of the new eigenstates. I can always express any state in terms of either set of eigenstates